# How can I load different storyboards depending on the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5

I am trying to:

1. detect device (iPhone 3.5", iPhone 4", iPad, ect)
2. load a different storyboard depending on what device and what size the application is running on.

I have watched some tutorials but I am still not getting it, can someone please type/show what code needs to go in the app delegate to achieve these goals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this in your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
        {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5s" bundle:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4" bundle:nil];
        }
    }  
    else
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    [window setRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: it is throwing errors at the last two line. It's saying window is an undeclared identifier and suggest _window. I tried its suggestions and now I just get a black screen and in the console it says "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch."

Comment: I had just forgotten to specify a view controller for the scene, it works, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I can not get my second view to link to the main view controller.h. The view loads but it does nothing because it's not linked, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you set the class of the view controller in the storyboard file?